# Repetir JQuery .animate() após clicar no botão

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Tenho o seguinte código:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#cadastre-se').click(function(){
     $('.icon-cracha').stop(true, true).delay(500).animate({top: "+0"},1000);
  });
  
});
```

```css
.icon-cracha{
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:-100px;
}

button{
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon-cracha"></div>  

<button id="cadastre-se" name="submit" class="btn">Próximo</button>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0twdvgn/)

Gostaria que esse efeito se repetisse todas as vezes que eu clicasse no botão `próximo`. Pq aqui no meu projeto ele so acontece no primeiro passo do cadastro, nos demais a bolinha ja aparece direito sem efeito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faz assim, declara o top dele negativo, assim a animação pode aparecer sempre.

```
    $('#cadastre-se').click(function(){
      $('.icon-cracha').css('top','-100px');
      $('.icon-cracha').stop(true, true).delay(500).animate({top: "+0"},1000);
  });
```

Ve e me fala se é isso que você precisa.

Fiz um exemplo para mostrar.
https://jsfiddle.net/rboschini/ensdzre1/

Comment: Cara era exatamente isso, muito obrigado!

Comment: Precisando de ajuda, da um toque!